# Geo Nodes scattering is different in solid and rendered view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, geometry-nodes, sculpting

I am scattering moss assets on all the faces that face in z direction. I didnt get it to work until I changed from rendered view to solid view and there it is exactly how I want it to be. Not sure if it is because of the scultping I did with multires modifier and subdiv modifier, although I have the same levels for viewport and render in both of them.

How it looks in solid view:

[image]

How it looks in rendered view:

[image]

Geo Nodes setup (Blue circle is the moss scattering):

[image]

Modifier Stack:

[image]